# Passing a single param instead of a list to Write() method of ItemWriter interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am using Spring Batch to read data from a CSV file and then save it into a database. So far all is good, except my input file contain a mixed data (multiple columns for multiple tables).

I created a class `CsvFileLine` that will contain  a whole line of the file, and implemented the interface `ItemReader<CsvFileLine>` and then implemented the interface `ItemProcessor<List<CsvFileLine>, ProcessorResult>` to whom I will pass a list of `CsvFileLine`and it returns an object of type `ProcessorResult` that I created also and contains 3 `ArrayList<>` of `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC`.

My problem now is when I need to implement the interface `ItemWriter<ProcessorResult>` the method `write(List<? extends T> items)` needs a list of items that are extending some other class while I intend to pass a single object which is ProcessorResult containing the 4 ArrayLists with the necessary data.

Can anyone suggest me how to deal with this case ? Is there a work around to pass only 1 parameter ?

Comment: 1.  Why are you not using the standard Spring Batch components for reading a CSV (`FlatFileItemReader`, etc)?
2.  There are a few different options for handling multiple item types and the `ItemWriter` abstraction.  Composition like in the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` is the most common approach.

Comment: How does a line in the CSV file relate to what you ultimately want to write to the database? Does one line in the file correspond to exactly one insert/update on the database as exactly one of `ClassA`, `ClassB`, or `ClassC`? Can one file line represent more than one instance of one of those classes? I think you're working against the Spring Batch framework here, but I can't offer many useful suggestions without knowing the actual end goal.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I am new to Spring Batch and I am following a common example wich I think is a standard in the house. Do you have any good examples of how to use use `FlatFileItemReader` without doing XML only annotations ?

Comment: @mymarkers actually the tables in the DB are the same as my POJOs (ClassA, ClassB and ClassC) and a single line of the file contain all the necessary data to add on instance of each. I hope this is clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification. If I understand correctly, you are saying that each line in the file contains one instance each of `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC`. I'll assume that for this example, but the solution would be similar even with a different relationship.

The key to setting up a Spring Batch job is to think about what constitutes an "item" and what you want to happen to it. You also need to understand how the framework passes the output of each interface as the input of the next. (Spring has nice [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html)). The return type of `ItemReader` is passed as a **singleton** to `ItemProcessor`. So in your case, the `ItemProcessor` should actually be `ItemProcessor<CsvFileLine, ProcessorResult>` instead of the `ItemProcessor<List<CsvFileLine>, ProcessorResult>` that you have.  The handoff from `ItemProcessor` to `ItemWriter` is a bit trickier. The `ItemWriter` implementation should take a `List` of the return type from the `ItemProcessor`. The `ItemWriter` takes a `List` because Spring Batch groups `ItemProcessor` output together into transactions. In your case, you could have `ItemWriter<List<ProcessorResult>>`.

With this foundation, we can change the structure of `ProcessorResult` and then the writer is easy to implement. Instead of a `ProcessorResult` containing *all* of the data in the file, it will contain the data from just one line:

```
public class ProcessorResult {
    private ClassA classA;
    private ClassB classB;
    private ClassC classC;
    // Constructor and getters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `ItemProcessor` takes one `CsvFileLine` and converts it to one `ProcessorResult`:

```
public class ExampleProcessor implements ItemProcessor<CsvFileLine, ProcessorResult> {

  public ProcessorResult process(CsvFileLine line){
    // mapping into ProcessorResult goes here
  }
```

The `ItemWriter` takes a `List` of these and needs to save them to the database. It could look something like this:

```
public class ExampleItemWriter implements ItemWriter<List<ProcessorResult>{

  private ClassADao classADao;
  private ClassBDao classBDao;
  private ClassCDao classCDao;

  public void write(List<? extends ProcessorResult> items){
     for(ProcessorResult result : items){
        classADao.save(result.getClassA());
        classBDao.save(result.getClassB());
        classCDao.save(result.getClassC());
     }
  }
}
```

Remember, each element in the `List` passed to `ItemWriter` maps back to a single item in the `ItemReader`. Usually, that would be a single line from the file, too. To use Spring Batch, you have to make sure that the return type of the `ItemReader` is the input type of the `ItemProcessor`. Meanwhile, the input to the `ItemWriter` is a `List` of the type returned by the `ItemProcessor`. The reader, processor, and writer that you have here do not follow that pattern and the framework would not be able to use them. A few small changes should allow you to use the code you've written within the framework.

Finally, I will note that you could probably do this without an `ItemProcessor` at all. You could just have `ItemReader<ProcessorResult>` and `ItemWriter<ProcessorResult>` and do the mapping in the `ItemReader`. So you move the logic from your current `ItemProcessor` instead into a `LineMapper<ProcessorResult>`. Then use that in a `FlatFileItemReader` and then everything is passed directly from reader to writer. It's beyond the scope of your question and I prefer XML configuration, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: thank you very match for your help. I will rewrite my code to follow the pattern you told me about and try to apply the business logic too. Actually the point that I am thinking about is how to establish the link between the different entities because for example `ClassA` have an attribute of type `List<ClassB> listClassB` and same for `classC` ..

Answer (score 0):

Since you've *chosen* to use Spring Batch and its `ItemWriter`, you need to have a firm idea of how your domain objects map to "Items".

Assuming that your `ProcessorResult` constitutes a single "Item", just call `ItemWriter.write()` with a list of size 1.

The standard Java API provides you `Collections.singletonList()` to do this conveniently.

```
 itemWriter.write(Collections.singletonList(processorResult));
```

Comment: Actually my `ProcessorResult` contains 3 ArrayLists : `processorResult.ListClassA`, `processorResult.ListClassB`  and `processorResult.ListClassC`. Every list contains more than 1 object.
Now I am thinking of making a dedicated writer for every ArrayList like `ItemWriter<ClassA>` ...

Comment: I don't know your domain, but you should probably make `ClassA`, `ClassB`, `ClassC` implement a common interface so you can treat them polymorphically.

Comment: and for `ItemProcessor`  each time I return a List of `ClassX` instead of returning an object encapsulating all of them ?